# Ecuación cuadrática con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

necesito ayuda en la gráfica de una ecuación de segundo grado, mi función de JavaScript resuelve la ecuación con los parámetros que el usuario ingresa y da como resultado las raíces y luego **intenta** graficar esa parábola, pero no sale como tendría que salir (se dibuja en cualquier lado de la pantalla y no sobre los ejes xy). Cualquier ayuda o aclaración me vendría bien ya que busqué mucho código en internet y no encuentro cómo realizar la gráfica con las raíces calculadas. Acá les muestro el código disculpen si es demasiado confuso o mal escrito, me faltan buenas prácticas, recién empiezo en el mundo de la programación. 
La función dibujargrilla dibuja el cuadriculado y las lineas de los ejes, la función ecuación toma los valores que el usuario ingreso en el html, calcula las raíces e intenta graficar la parábola, y la funcion validanumero permite que el usuario ingrese solo números y no letras.

```js
function dibujargrilla() {
    var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    for(let i=0;i<canvas.height;i+=10){
        ctx.moveTo(0,i+10);
        ctx.strokeStyle="#9c9c9c";
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,i+10);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    for(let t=0;t<canvas.width;t+=10){
        ctx.moveTo(t+10,0);
        ctx.strokeStyle="#9c9c9c";
        ctx.lineTo(t+10,canvas.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2,0);
    ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2,canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function ecuacion(){
    resultados = document.getElementById("raices");

    var a = Number(document.rellenar.vc.value);
    var b = Number(document.rellenar.vl.value);
    var c = Number(document.rellenar.vi.value);
    var d;

    if (a==0)
    {
        var x1= (-c)/b;
        var x2=0;
    }
    else {
        d=b*b-4*a*c;
        if(d>0)
        {
            var x1 = (-b+(Math.sqrt(d)))/(2*a);
            var x2 = (-b-(Math.sqrt(d)))/(2*a);
        }
        if(d==0)
        {
            var x1= (-b)/2*a;
            var x2= (-b)/2*a;
        }
        if (d<0)
        {
            alert("Raices Imaginarias");
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("x1").value = Number(x1.toFixed(2));
    document.getElementById("x2").value = Number(x2.toFixed(2));

    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidht= 6;
    ctx.strokeStyle= "#001f33";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(document.getElementById("x1").value,canvas.width/2);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(canvas.height/2,document.getElementById("vi").value,document.getElementById("x2").value,canvas.width/2);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function validanumero(elemento){
    if (!/^([0-9\-])*$/.test(elemento.value)){
        alert("Ingrese solo numeros");
        elemento.value = '';
    }
}
```

```css
.graficot{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10em;
    width: 640px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body onload="dibujargrilla()">

    <div id="titulo">
        <header>
            <h1>Sistema de ecuaciones</h1>
        </header>
    </div>

    <form action="#" name="rellenar">
        <h3>Ingrese las variables:</h3>
        <div id="variables">
            <p><input type="text" size="2" id="vc" name="vc" onchange="return validanumero(this)" > X<sup>2</sup>+<input type="text" size="2" id="vl" name="vl" onchange="return validanumero(this)" > X+<input type="text" size="2" id="vi" name="vi" onchange="return validanumero(this)" >=0</p>
        </div>
    <h1><input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="ecuacion()"></h1>
    </form>


        <div id="raices">
        <h3>Resultado:</h3>
        <p>X1=<input disabled="disabled" size="3" id="x1"></p>
        <p>X2=<input disabled="disabled" size="3" id="x2"></p>
        </div>

        <canvas id="mycanvas" class="graficot" width="640" height="400">
        </canvas>

    <div class="volver">
        <a href="inicio.html">Inicio</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben incluir un [mcve].

Comment: Ya agregué el HTML, gracias por avisar @alanfcm

Comment: El HTML llama una función `validanumero` pero esta no está incluida en el código. El código debe incluir todo lo necesario para reproducir el problema, si esta función no es necesaria para ello, retírala del código y asegúrate que se pueda ejecutar en Stack Snippet.

Comment: @Rubén gracias por comentar, disculpa que no sepa bien cómo preguntar soy nuevo en el foro, ahí compartí el código que creo que es necesario para que el que lea pueda entender mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

`quadraticCurveTo` no grafica directamente una ecuación de segundo grado, lo que hace es graficar una [curva cuatrática de Bézier](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curva_de_B%C3%A9zier#Curvas_cuadr%C3%A1ticas_de_B%C3%A9zier) para ello toma como punto inicial la posición del "path", los primeros dos argumentos se utilizan para determinar el **punto de control** y los últimos dos argumentos para determinar el **punto final**.

De la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22238597/1595451) a [How to model quadratic equation using a bezier curve (calculate control point)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22237780/1595451) (Cómo modelar una ecuación cuatrática usand una curva de bezier (calcular el punto de control)), una forma aproximada de calcular el punto de control es la siguiente:

```
// calc a control point
var cpX = 2*anywhereOnCurveX -startX/2 -endX/2;
var cpY = 2*anywhereOnCurveY -startY/2 -endY/2;
```

- `anywhereOnCurveX`  es la coordenada X de un punto conocido, esta podría ser una raíz.
- `anywhereOnCurveY`  es la coordenada Y de un punto conocido, si se usa una raíz, entonces esto sería 0
- `startX`, `startY` son las coordenadas del punto inicial, este punto deberás determinarlo, por ejemplo con base en la el tamaño del canvas
- `endX`, `endY` son las coordenadas del punto final, lo mismo del punto anterior.